# Lighting the chanukah menorah and the shabbos candles in the same place

Tags: shabbat, chanuka

I seem to recall a halacha stating that the Chanukah menorah should not be lit in the same place as the Shabbos candles are lit.  Is this indeed the halacha, and can someone point me to somewhere where this is written?   Thanks.

Comment: see Rama 671:7 https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%90_%D7%96

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of the achronim stress that you should light chanukkah candles before shabbas candles to avoid the light from the shabbas candles, which implies that they are being lit in the same place. But I could see the jump from that to deliberately lighting them apart to avoid the issue. Also if you're machmir about lighting the chanukkah candles somewhere particular, e.g. outside, next to the door, etc., I assume that puts them away from your shabbas candles.

Comment: "to avoid the light from the shabbas candles" What does this mean? Can you edit in an example of who says this?

Comment: I phrased this very poorly. The idea is that you should light the Shabbas candles without interference from other light sources. Today we light with electric lights on anyway, but still. Otzar search turns up this exact argument in אליבא דהלכתא (ק). Relatedly, the Pri Megadim (679)  stresses that you should not prepare your shabbas candles until after you've lit your chanukkah candles to avoid "embarrassment", which has the same implication. So says a book called שיעורי פרי אליעזר on Otzar.